# Faster way to access the last and the first element of a List<int>

Tags: c#

The language I use is C#.

Let

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
```

be a list of integers, that we want to use them to do some calculations. Is it faster to access the first element of the list as

```
numbers[0]
```

or as

```
numbers.First()
```

Also, if we want to access the last element of the list it is faster to access it as

```
numbers[numbers.Count-1]
```

or as

```
numbers.Last()
```

Comment: Regardless of what is faster, please keep in mind that this is **micro-optimization**. `First()` and `Last()` are more semantic in your code, they express better what you want.

Comment: It wouldn't be a micro-optimization if `.Last()` was an O(N) operation. Fortunately, it isn't - it's O(1). Unfortunately, this fact isn't explicitly documented in MSDN. Theoretically, they could change the implementation to O(N) without telling you. (They never will, though)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It's premature optimization. Is there working code yet? "If it doesn't work, it doesn't matter how fast it doesn't work".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` extensions check type of source when you do `First()` or `Last()`. If source is `IList<T>` then indexing is used:

```
IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
if (list != null)
{
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        return list[0];
    }
}
```

So, enumerator will not be created and performance will be almost same. But simple indexing will be of course faster.

Comment: One thing that's my concern and the reason why I wrote that question is that I think, when we call list.Count, each time we count one element after the other. So that takes more time as the list gets longer. Probably, I am wrong, but at least that was my concern. Is that true?

Comment: @ChristosPaisios `Count` property for `List` is `O(1)`, so it doesn't take more time as the list gets longer. Note that `IEnumerable`'s `Count()` **function** may enumerate (actually need to count the items).

Comment: @ChristosPaisios nope, `list.Count` just returns size of internal array, which it uses for storing items. It will not enumerate elements one after the other. Btw `Count()` extension uses same approach as `First()` - if source is `ICollection` then it's `Count` property value will be returned and nothing will be enumerated.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky and David S. thank you both for your valuable comments. I didn't know it that list.Count just returns size of internal array. So the Count property is O(1). Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

The index-based accesses (`numbers[0]` and `numbers[numbers.Count - 1]`, respectively) are probably faster by a very minimal degree, as `First()` and `Last()` require the additional method calls of the extension methods `First()` and `Last()` before accessing the list items (based on their index, again).

Comment: If "probably" isn't a good enough answer, then you should have tried it yourself and _measured_.

Comment: @user3038092: *Probably*, because no-one knows what wonders future .NET versions and alternative implementations might do to avoid the actual internal call of the indexer.

Answer (score 2):

In case of a `List<T>`, both `numbers[0]` and `numbers.First()` will fall back to the same implementation, so there is no significant difference. The same stands for `Last()`.